# essbase: How can i export without double quotes in data files using dataexport commands in MaxL?

Tags: essbase

i am exporting data from Essbase cubes using MAXL SET DATAEXPORT commands. But data file consists of double quotes to members.! 
How can i export without double quotes in data files using dataexport commands in MaxL?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option that I am aware of to turn this off. You want the quotes because it's possible to have a comma in a member name – if there were no quotes then member names with commas would really mess up the data load.

The question you should be asking yourself is seeing if the tool consuming the data file can work with the quotes. Most CSV readers handle this. If you really, really, really need to get rid of the double quotes then you might try using a stream editor like sed or even tr to remove them.

If you find this answer helpful please indicate as such so that more people are encouraged to answer Essbase questions!